# Synergy on Mavericks (OSX 10.9) and enable assistive devices

Tags: synergy, osx-mavericks

Mavericks handles accessibility on a per-application basis, so instead of enabling assistive devices (option does not even exist) carte-blanche, the app which makes the request shows up in a list in `System Preferences > Security & Privacy > Privacy` where you can enable the access it's looking for.

Synergy, however, makes a check for the old style of assistive devices setting and fails to start.

**Update**: For those catching up with this issue - Synergy seems to have resolved this with 1.4.17 release.

Also, for those experiencing problems after upgrading, please see James Valero's input below.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

From a terminal:

```
sudo open /Applications/Synergy.app/Contents/MacOS/Synergy
```

Then open OSX System Preferences and click **Security & Privacy**, then click on **Privacy** and then **Accessibility**

Check the checkbox on for **Terminal** and **Synergy**.

[image]
You can then close Synergy and start it again in the background through the terminal:

```
/Applications/Synergy.app/Contents/MacOS/Synergy &
```

I expect this will be fixed in the next release (1.4.16 Beta)

Source: http://synergy-foss.org/osqa/questions/1999/error-1410-on-mac-1081

Comment: This solution works ONLY if you restart synergy via the Terminal. I.e. not from the Dock. I assume Terminal (as the container for Synergy now) is the "means" to which Synergy is gaining access to the accessibility features.

Comment: I would emphasize that you have to tick the checkbox for Terminal, without it this wouldn't work at all.

Comment: I followed these steps and it didn't work :(  -- On Mavericks, fresh install of Synergy 1.4.15 Beta -- I have Terminal.app and Synergy checked on `System Preferences > Security & Privacy > Privacy` -- still getting the error: `FATAL: Init failed: system setting not enabled: "Enable access for assistive devices"
Try 'synergys --help' for more information.`

Comment: Nevermind... i did get it working with these instructions, but I use `iTerm` and I had to (scroll up and) find that and enable it under `Privacy` as well. -- fyi, a good debugging command: `/Applications/Synergy.app/Contents/MacOS/synergys --config ~/.synergy.conf`

Answer (score 3):

If it's still not working after rebooting, it seems that Mavericks needs the settings to be "reset" if you've already had this setup before. To get it working again, I had to untick Terminal / Synergy.app, lock, unlock, re-tick Terminal/Synergy.app, lock, then it worked. Now Synergy starts normally without needing the terminal anymore.

Answer (score 2):

The just-released 1.4.16 Beta version for OS X 10.9 now resolves this issue and allows Synergy to be opened directly rather than requiring sudo.

Note: After installing Synergy-1.4.16 and opening it the first time I had to reboot to get the appropriate Accessibility preference to become available.